# How to cast Object to FSharp List

Tags: casting, f#

I have a .NET method which has a signature that returns an object. But I know that the actual type being returned is an FSharp List of Foo.
How do I downcast the object to a list ?

I've tried the following but all I get is an `InvalidCastException`

```
let result = Class.MethodReturningObject()
let lst = result :?> (Foo list)
```

**EDIT**

For anyone that lands here. The execption I was getting was not related to the cast and the above code. It was related to Linqpad. The above code will execute just fine in Visual Studio, but it will return a `List<Foo>` not an F# List.

The accepted answer will produce an F# List.

Comment: This? http://www.fssnip.net/oD/title/Cast-object-list

Comment: I think that casts a list of objects, my list is an object, that I need to cast to a list of member types (ie Foo list)

Comment: Check out the duplicate post I linked at the top of this page.  If you don't see it, refresh the page.

Comment: Did read that post, but it descended into patterns by the op, and it all got confusing.  I think my question is more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`box: 'T -> obj` and `unbox: obj -> 'T` are generic functions converting any F# data to and from the universal type `System.Object` (the F# type `obj`).

Thus the following should work in your case:

```
let lst: Foo list = Class.MethodReturningObject() |> unbox
```

Comment: Care to provide at least a little bit of explanation?